# Itext magnify picture

Tags: java, image, itext, magnify

Is it possible to make the generated pdf document interactive by iText.

I want it to have the option to **magnify a picture/thumbnail** by a mouseclick to see the details.

**Does iText have such option and is there an example**

Comment: This can be achieved by adding an annotation with a larger version of the picture of which the *visibility status* can be turned *on* or *off* using a mouse event. I currently don't have the time to make an example (are you using the old iText 5 or the new iText 7), but I hope that these keywords (annotation, mouse events,...) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I use the old iText 5. Is this functionality added to iText 7 or also available on iText 5?At least now I know where look for.

Comment: Yes, iText 5 also allows you to add annotations. Take a look at these examples for inspiration: [text appears on mouse over](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7#312-movieposters2.java), [pop up](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-pop-window-display-images-and-text), [show / hide content](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7#296-advertisement.java),...